# bison giving me a syntax error while the syntax is correct?

Tags: c, compiler-construction, bison, flex-lexer

i am currently doing an assignment where i have to make a mini compiler for a programing language using flex and bison when testing the parser generated by flex and bison with a program test it keeps giving me syntax error while the test i wrote should have a correct syntax

here is the flex code

```
%{
#include"synt.tab.h"
extern nb_ligne;
extern col;
int i;
%}
lettre [a-zA-Z]
chiffre[0-9]
IDF {lettre}({lettre}|{chiffre})*
CST_INT ([+-]?[1-9]{chiffre}*)|0
CST_REAL {CST_INT}"."({chiffre}+)
CST_CHAR \'.\'
CST_CHAINE \".+\"
CST_LOGIC TRUE|FALSE
COMMENT "%"(([^";"]|\n)*";")
%%
{COMMENT} { 
          for(i=0;i<strlen(yytext);i++){if(yytext[i] == '\n' ){nb_ligne ++;  col = 1;     }  col++; }}
PROGRAM      col+=strlen(yytext); printf("l'entite lexicale reconnue est %s mc\n",yytext);   return  mc_program;
ROUTINE      col+=strlen(yytext); printf("l'entite lexicale reconnue est %s mc\n",yytext);   return  mc_routine;
END          col+=strlen(yytext); printf("l'entite lexicale reconnue est %s mc\n",yytext);   return  mc_end ;
ENDR         col+=strlen(yytext); printf("l'entite lexicale reconnue est %s mc\n",yytext);   return  mc_endr ;
LOGICAL      col+=strlen(yytext); printf("l'entite lexicale reconnue est %s mc\n",yytext);   return  mc_logical;
CHARACTER    col+=strlen(yytext); printf("l'entite lexicale reconnue est %s mc\n",yytext);   return  mc_character;
INTEGER      col+=strlen(yytext); printf("l'entite lexicale reconnue est %s mc\n",yytext);   return  mc_integer ;
REAL         col+=strlen(yytext); printf("l'entite lexicale reconnue est %s mc\n",yytext);   return  mc_real;
DIMENSION    col+=strlen(yytext); printf("l'entite lexicale reconnue est %s mc\n",yytext);   return  mc_dimension; 
READ         col+=strlen(yytext); printf("l'entite lexicale reconnue est %s mc\n",yytext);   return  mc_read ;
WRITE        col+=strlen(yytext); printf("l'entite lexicale reconnue est %s mc\n",yytext);   return  mc_write ;
IF           col+=strlen(yytext); printf("l'entite lexicale reconnue est %s mc\n",yytext);   return  mc_if;
THEN         col+=strlen(yytext); printf("l'entite lexicale reconnue est %s mc\n",yytext);   return mc_then; 
ELSE         col+=strlen(yytext); printf("l'entite lexicale reconnue est %s mc\n",yytext);   return mc_else ;
ENDIF        col+=strlen(yytext); printf("l'entite lexicale reconnue est %s mc\n",yytext);   return mc_endif ;
DOWHILE      col+=strlen(yytext); printf("l'entite lexicale reconnue est %s mc\n",yytext);   return mc_dowhile; 
ENDDO        col+=strlen(yytext); printf("l'entite lexicale reconnue est %s mc\n",yytext);   return  mc_enddo ;
CALL         col+=strlen(yytext); printf("l'entite lexicale reconnue est %s mc\n",yytext);   return  mc_call ;
EQUIVALENCE  col+=strlen(yytext);  printf("l'entite lexicale reconnue est %s mc\n",yytext);  return  mc_equivalence;
OR           col+=strlen(yytext);  printf("l'entite lexicale reconnue est %s mc\n",yytext);  return  mc_or ;
AND          col+=strlen(yytext); printf("l'entite lexicale reconnue est %s mc\n",yytext);   return  mc_and ;
GT           col+=strlen(yytext); printf("l'entite lexicale reconnue est %s mc\n",yytext);   return  mc_gt ;
GE           col+=strlen(yytext); printf("l'entite lexicale reconnue est %s mc\n",yytext);   return  mc_ge ;
EQ           col+=strlen(yytext); printf("l'entite lexicale reconnue est %s mc\n",yytext);   return  mc_eq ;
NE           col+=strlen(yytext);  printf("l'entite lexicale reconnue est %s mc\n",yytext);  return  mc_ne ;
LE           col+=strlen(yytext); printf("l'entite lexicale reconnue est %s mc\n",yytext);   return  mc_le ;
LT           col+=strlen(yytext);  printf("l'entite lexicale reconnue est %s mc\n",yytext);  return  mc_lt ;
"+"          col+=strlen(yytext); printf("l'entite lexicale reconnue est %s mc\n",yytext);   return  mc_add;
"-"          col+=strlen(yytext);  printf("l'entite lexicale reconnue est %s mc\n",yytext);  return  mc_sub ;
"*"          col+=strlen(yytext);  printf("l'entite lexicale reconnue est %s mc\n",yytext);  return  mc_mult ;
"/"          col+=strlen(yytext);  printf("l'entite lexicale reconnue est %s mc\n",yytext);  return  mc_div ;
"="          col+=strlen(yytext);  printf("l'entite lexicale reconnue est %s mc\n",yytext);  return  mc_aff;
"("          col+=strlen(yytext);  printf("l'entite lexicale reconnue est %s mc\n",yytext);  return  mc_par_ouv; 
")"          col+=strlen(yytext);  printf("l'entite lexicale reconnue est %s mc\n",yytext);  return  mc_par_fer; 
";"          col+=strlen(yytext);  printf("l'entite lexicale reconnue est %s mc\n",yytext);  return  mc_pvg ;
","          col+=strlen(yytext);  printf("l'entite lexicale reconnue est %s mc\n",yytext);  return  mc_vg  ;    
"."          col+=strlen(yytext);  printf("l'entite lexicale reconnue est %s mc\n",yytext);  return  mc_pt ;   
{CST_LOGIC}  col+=strlen(yytext);  printf("l'entite lexicale reconnue est %s mc\n",yytext);  return  cst_logic; 

{IDF} { col+=strlen(yytext); 
if(yyleng>10) printf("erreur: ligne %d et la colonne %d idf long\n",nb_ligne,col);
else{ printf("l'entite lexicale reconnue est %s IDF\n",yytext); return idf;}} 

{CST_INT}   { col+=strlen(yytext);
if(atoi(yytext)<=32767 && atoi(yytext)>= -32768){ printf ("l'entite lexicale reconnue est %s cst int\n",yytext);}
else { printf(" erreur: la ligne %d et la colonne %d depassement de la capacite\n ",nb_ligne,col); return cst_int;}}

{CST_REAL} {  col+=strlen(yytext);  
if(atoi(yytext)<=32767 && atoi(yytext)>= -32768){ printf ("l'entite lexicale reconnue est %s cst real\n",yytext);}
else { printf(" erreur: la ligne %d et la colonne %d depassement de la capacite\n",nb_ligne,col); return cst_real;}}

{CST_CHAR}   {col+=strlen(yytext);    printf ("l'entite lexicale reconnue est %s cst char\n",yytext); return cst_char;}
{CST_CHAINE} {col+=strlen(yytext);    printf ("l'entite lexicale reconnue est %s cst chaine\n",yytext); return cst_chaine;}
[ \t]
\n { col=1;  nb_ligne++; }
. printf("erreur lexical a la ligne %d et la col %d\n",nb_ligne,col);
%%
```

and here is the bison code

```
%{
 int nb_ligne=1; int col=1; 
%}
%token mc_program mc_routine mc_end mc_endr mc_logical mc_character mc_integer mc_real mc_dimension  mc_read mc_write mc_if mc_then mc_else mc_endif mc_dowhile mc_enddo mc_call mc_equivalence mc_or mc_and mc_gt mc_ge mc_eq mc_ne mc_lt mc_le mc_add mc_sub mc_mult mc_div mc_aff mc_par_ouv mc_par_fer mc_pvg mc_vg mc_pt cst_logic idf cst_int cst_real cst_char cst_chaine
%start S


%%
S: LIST_FONC mc_program idf DEC LIST_INST mc_end  {printf("prog syntaxiquement correct");YYACCEPT;}
;
LIST_FONC: DEC_FONC LIST_FONC|DEC_FONC
;
DEC_FONC: 
       TYPE mc_routine idf mc_par_ouv LIST_PAR mc_par_fer DEC LIST_INST AFF mc_endr
;
TYPE:
    mc_integer | mc_real | mc_character | mc_logical
;
LIST_PAR:
        VAR mc_vg LIST_IDF|VAR
; 
VAR:
    idf|TAB|MAT
;
TAB: idf mc_par_ouv EXP mc_par_fer
;
MAT: idf mc_par_ouv EXP mc_vg EXP mc_par_fer 
;
VAL_RET:cst_chaine|cst_char|EXP
;
DEC:
   DEC DEC_VAR  |DEC DEC_TAB |DEC DEC_MAT |DEC DEC_CH | DEC_VAR |DEC_TAB|DEC_MAT| DEC_CH
;
DEC_VAR:
        TYPE LIST_IDF mc_pvg
;
LIST_IDF: idf mc_vg LIST_IDF |idf 
;
DEC_TAB:
        TYPE idf mc_dimension mc_par_ouv cst_int mc_par_fer mc_pvg
;
DEC_MAT:
       TYPE idf  mc_dimension mc_par_ouv cst_int mc_vg cst_int mc_par_fer mc_pvg
;
DEC_CH:
       TYPE idf mc_mult cst_int mc_pvg
;
LIST_INST: LIST_INST INST| INST
;
INST:
    AFF | ES  | COND  | BOUCLE  | EQUIVALENCE  
;
AFF:
    idf mc_aff EXP mc_pvg | idf mc_aff cst_chaine mc_pvg | idf mc_aff cst_char mc_pvg| idf mc_aff cst_logic mc_pvg| idf mc_aff mc_call idf mc_par_ouv LIST_IDF mc_par_fer mc_pvg| idf mc_aff VAL_RET
;       
EXP:
    TERM | TERM mc_add EXP | TERM mc_sub EXP
;
TERM: FACT | FACT mc_mult TERM | FACT mc_div TERM
;
FACT: idf| cst_int | cst_real
;
ES:
   mc_read mc_par_ouv idf mc_par_fer mc_pvg;| mc_write mc_par_ouv cst_chaine mc_vg idf mc_vg cst_chaine mc_par_fer mc_pvg
;
COND: mc_if mc_par_ouv EXP_COND mc_par_fer mc_then LIST_INST mc_else LIST_INST mc_endif
;
EXP_COND:
        mc_par_ouv TERM_LOG mc_pt mc_or mc_pt EXP_COND mc_par_fer | mc_par_ouv TERM_LOG mc_pt mc_and mc_pt EXP_COND mc_par_fer|TERM_LOG
;
TERM_LOG: mc_par_ouv EXP mc_pt mc_eq EXP mc_par_fer |mc_par_ouv EXP mc_pt mc_ne EXP mc_par_fer |mc_par_ouv EXP mc_pt mc_le EXP mc_par_fer |mc_par_ouv EXP mc_pt mc_lt mc_pt EXP mc_par_fer |mc_par_ouv EXP mc_pt mc_ge EXP mc_par_fer |mc_par_ouv EXP mc_pt mc_gt EXP mc_par_fer
;        
BOUCLE: mc_dowhile mc_par_ouv EXP_COND mc_par_fer LIST_INST mc_enddo
;
EQUIVALENCE: mc_equivalence mc_par_ouv LIST_IDF mc_par_fer mc_vg mc_par_ouv LIST_IDF mc_par_fer mc_pvg

%%
main()
{
yyparse();
}
yywrap()
{}
int yyerror(char *msg)
{ printf(" Erreur syntaxique a ligne : %d a la colonne %d ", nb_ligne,col);
   return 1;  
}
```

and here is a code sample that i tested with i tested more than this

```
  INTEGER ROUTINE fonc(A,B)
A=B+1;
fonc=A;
ENDR

PROGRAM
projet
INTEGER d Dimension;
INTEGER C;
CHARACTER chaine;
CHARACTER char;
C=call fonc(c,d(2));
END
```

and here is the result [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qotch.png) the semantics don't have to be right since i haven't done that part yet

i think its due the grammar being wrong since the lexer works fine on its own, how do i make sure my grammar is correct as i am a beginner

Comment: And where are (1)the test data and (2) the error message showing which line of the test data caused the syntax error?

Comment: excuse me , i just added them

Comment: See this for information on how to debug your program: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50821203/how-can-i-debug-my-flex-bison-grammar. You can also add `%error-verbose` to your parser to get better error messages. And don't paste code as images, please.